# VBScript to send a link to file AND folder

Tags: file, vbscript, path, outlook

In Windows 7, I've got a VBScript that creates an email in Outlook with a link to the file when you right-click in Windows Explorer. The script is run by creating a shortcut to it and adding it to  %userprofile%\SendTo (which shows up in the Send to when you right-click the file). The goal is to be able to send a link to the file and the folder that contains it, rather than sending it as an attachment. It works fine except it always give a link directly to the file. How do I modify it so it also provides a link to the folder in the second line?

```
Const olMailItem = 0
Const olFolderInbox = 6

If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
WScript.Quit
End If

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = 'outlook.exe'")

If colItems.Count = 0 Then
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
objFolder.Display
End If

strFile = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
objItem.Subject = "Here is a link to a file..."
objItem.HTMLBody = "Link to the file: <A HREF=" & Chr(34) & "file://" & strFile & Chr(34) & ">" & strFile & "</A><BR>Link to the folder: <A HREF=" & Chr(34) & "file://" & strFile & Chr(34) & ">" & strFile & "</A>"
objItem.Display
```

Might be a simple answer, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you need to correct the HTML markup set to the HTMLBody property.

Comment: Hum, could you read a file content using next link (the same as if I send this link via e-mail), e.g. `file:///D:/xxx/ddd/_Listing.txt`? A real file in my computer....

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes. The HTMLbody code is wrong, but as a newbie to VBS I don't know how to call the path without the file name.

Comment: @JosefZ I'm not looking to read the contents, just need the path isolated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileSystemObject` object and it's `GetParentFolderName` method could help. Note that for any of methods used (in next script) hold: a method works only on the provided path string. It does not attempt to resolve the path, nor does it check for the existence of the specified path.

```
option explicit

Dim strFile, FSO, oFile

If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
  strFile = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
Else
  strFile = "D:\Remote\bat\COCL\bu bu bu\somefile.ext"
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Wscript.Echo "FSO 'path' methods" & vbNewLine & "---------------------" _
   & vbNewLine & "GetAbsolutePathName: " & FSO.GetAbsolutePathName( strFile) _
   & vbNewLine & "GetParentFolderName: " & FSO.GetParentFolderName( strFile) _
   & vbNewLine & "GetDriveName: " & FSO.GetDriveName( strFile) _
   & vbNewLine & "GetBaseName: " & FSO.GetBaseName( strFile) _
   & vbNewLine & "GetExtensionName: " & FSO.GetExtensionName( strFile) _
   & vbNewLine & "GetFileName: " & FSO.GetFileName( strFile)

Set FSO = Nothing
Wscript.Quit
```